# apacite force showing of all sources in .bib file

Tags: apacite

I was wondering if the apacite package allowed for forcing all sources (in the .bib file) to show in the biblography. This is due to my main document having a pdf within it, which uses intext references.
I would like those sources to be shown in my main document's biblography, instead of having two.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can't you use `\nocite{*}`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the embedded pdf section of your document contains citation call-outs to bibliographic entries with keys (say) `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`. It suffices to issue the command

```
\nocite{a,b,c,d}
```

in order to generate the corresponding formatted entries in the bibliography.